# Docker container stops after ENTRYPOINT

Tags: angular, docker, deployment, environment-variables

We have an Angular front-end app running in a Docker container. Due to some pipeline changes, we have set up the app to grab config files at run time. I've updated the Dockerfile to run a shell script to set up configuration files available to our Angular app inside the container to load at run-time - but, obviously the container should continue to run after the script is done to host the Angular app.

```
  
FROM internal.resource

ENV SERVICE_NAME my_app

COPY deployfile /app/
COPY deployfile /etc/nginx/
COPY dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html/
COPY default.conf ./conf.d

USER root
RUN chown appuser /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/config/
USER appuser

COPY --chown=appuser:appuser start.sh .
RUN chmod a+x ./start.sh

# Adding this line causes container to stop after its run
ENTRYPOINT ["./start.sh"]
# This line (I kinda copied it from somewhere else) keeps the container up
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

EXPOSE 8080
```

The problem is, after adding the ENTRYPOINT, my container kept dying immediately after running. Adding the `CMD [nginx...]` line keeps the container up, but I only used that line after seeing it in another team's script. The container isn't even leveraging nginx to serve the application and certainly wasn't needed in the script before I added the ENTRYPOINT.

Before adding ENTRYPOINT, the container ran fine, the Angular app just didn't have the right config file. After adding ENTRYPOINT, the container dies after the script is run. But the container is still responsible for hosting the Angular app.

Edit: Keeping the container up is important because it contains our front end angular app. The start script just sets up the configuration file for the app to use.

Comment: A container runs only one command and then exits.  If your image has an `ENTRYPOINT`, that is the single command; the `CMD` is [passed as additional parameters to it](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact).  What's in the `start.sh` script?  If the container isn't supposed to be running Nginx, then what is it supposed to be doing (why is "keep the container up" important)?

Comment: Edited the post for clarity

Comment: A container wraps a single process; it's not really a container for files or configuration.  What should the container actually do; or if it doesn't need to run a process, why is it a problem that it exits?

Answer (score 1):

ENTRYPOINT and CMD can be a little confusing. In your Dockerfile, they work more like a command and the parameters for the command.

What gets run is actually `./start.sh nginx -g daemon off;` which is probably not what you want.

If you specify something after the image name in a `docker run` command, that would replace the CMD statement, but the ENTRYPOINT would stay. So if you say `docker run my_image_name ls -al`, the command that would be run would be `./start.sh ls -al`.

You can only run one command when your container starts. If you want to be able to easily override it, you should put it in a CMD statement. If you don't want it to be easily overridden, you should put it in an ENTRYPOINT statement.

To run both commands, you can pass them to a shell like this

```
FROM internal.resource

ENV SERVICE_NAME my_app

COPY deployfile /app/
COPY deployfile /etc/nginx/
COPY dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html/
COPY default.conf ./conf.d

USER root
RUN chown appuser /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/config/
USER appuser

COPY --chown=appuser:appuser start.sh .
RUN chmod a+x ./start.sh

CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "./start.sh && nginx -g daemon off;"]

EXPOSE 8080
```

Now you only have one command. It'll run a shell and that will run the two commands you want.

Alternatively, you can add `nginx -g daemon off;` at the bottom of your start.sh script and only run `./start.sh` either as the ENTRYPOINT or CMD.

The reason that adding the CMD to your Dockerfile keeps it up might be that your script runs whatever is passed as a parameter before exiting. That's pretty common. That would usually be done with a line like `exec "$@"` at the end of the script. If that's the case, then you can just keep your Dockerfile as it is.

Comment: You're exactly right, my start script has `exec "$@"` at the end of it (also borrowed from the other team). So what you're saying makes a lot of sense. But what if I just wanted to remove the nginx line and but still have the container run so long as `start.sh` ran as well. The nginx line does nothing but keep the container running.

Comment: If the entrypoint script ends with `exec "$@"` (which it usually should) then the combined `./start.sh nginx ...` command is in fact exactly what you want.

Comment: Yes, it does work like this. But am I just running nginx arbitrarily to keep the container open? Why isn't it sufficient that I have my angular app on there? That's the purpose of the container. I only run nginx because ENTRYPOINT causes the container to stop running.

Comment: @Asif The normal behavior of a container is to exit when the command finishes. It sounds like you want to keep it running. The Angular app doesn't run in the container. It runs in a browser. To be able to run the Angular app, you need a web server like nginx to serve the files to a browser.

Comment: Why does the container (and Angular app) continue running when you don't have the ENTRYPOINT?